# csv file is changing when I just open it and save it again without editing it

Tags: excel, matlab, csv

I am using a software that starts by importing in it some csv files. These csv files are given to me but I need to make some changes and import them again in that software in order to take some results. If I just open these csv files and without doing any changes save them again I am getting a message writing 'Some features in your workbook might be lost'. If I import the new csv file that in reality they are the same with before the software I am using is not possible to run.

As I understand there is something that changes in the csv files only from opening them and saving them. Does anybody knows what is happening?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: why dont you share your code with us and let us know, which matlab version you are using and which OS?

Comment: The code is not mine and I can't share it. By opening the original csv files and the new ones (that I just created by only opening and saving again the original files) with notepad I found out that excel is adding some extra semicolons. What I don't understand is why excel is not able to save the csv files as they were when I opened them. 

I am using excel 2016, windows 10 and matlab R2019a

Comment: Long story short, not knowing what exactly you are doing, and not seeing any examples of what happens, it will be very difficult for anyone to help you.

Comment: @pol If you open the file in Notepad before you do anything with it in Excel, does it have the correct number of deliminator characters (semicolons?) on each line?  Or, is Excel correcting 'short' lines with Nulls at the end?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example csv file:

```
toto,titi,tata
1,2,3,4,5
1,2,3,4
1,2,3
1,2
1
1,2,3,4,5
1,2,3,4
1,2,3
1,2
1
```

Notice that not each row has the same number of elements. If I load it into Excel then save it back as a `csv` file, excel will add the necessary delimiters (`,` in my example) so every row will have the same number of "*column*" (even if some are empty).
Sure enough, if I open (in a normal text editor) the new `.csv` file saved by excel, I get:

```
toto,titi,tata,,
1,2,3,4,5
1,2,3,4,
1,2,3,,
1,2,,,
1,,,,
1,2,3,4,5
1,2,3,4,
1,2,3,,
1,2,,,
1,,,,
```

This is the behaviour of Excel and I couldn't find an option in Excel to change that. If this is what makes your program import fail, you'll have to consider making your changes to the `csv` file from a normal text editor (which doesn't make automatic assumtions like Excel).